# Objects cloned when sent to a web worker in Chrome, not IE10

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to better understand if/how browsers clone values when they're sent to web workers.

I'm debugging a js library we're using - they use a web worker which internally calls `delete d.children` - this doesn't affect the original object sent to the web worker - ***except in IE10***

Workers support the structured cloning algorithm so that objects can be passed - but I'm not understanding why this isn't affecting IE. Do they *not* clone?

I'm debugging jstree - unfortunately.

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/dist/jstree.js#L1502

The relevant code is the function they call inside the web worker.

```
func = function (data, undefined) {
```

Inside this function, they eventually call `delete d.children`, so I manually try it at the very top for testing.

This line DOES NOT impact original data object in Chrome, DOES in IE10/Windows 7

```
delete data.dat[0].children;
```

In IE10, the data object we provided jstree (results from an xhr call) suddenly loses its `children` property.

That worker is passed data here:

https://github.com/vakata/jstree/blob/master/dist/jstree.js#L1847

```
w.postMessage(args);
```

Trying my manual delete again:

```
delete args.dat[0].children;
```

Does delete the property as expected, in *all* browsers.

Comment: There should be no shared objects between webWorker and main thread or between webWorkers because having an actual shared object creates synchronization issues.  Thus objects "sent" between are copied and become new and separate objects.  Any synchronization of properties must be done manually via messaging.  You'd have to show a more specific example of what you're seeing in IE10 for us to offer more insight as to what is happening.

Comment: according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Browser_compatibility IE10 does

Comment: According to [Microsoft's own article about webWorkers in IE10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/01/web-workers-in-ie10-background-javascript-makes-web-apps-faster.aspx), it does support the structured cloning.  It would pretty much be hopelessly broken and limited if it did not.

Comment: I've posted further details about the issue. JStree's source code is a disaster and a pain in the neck to deal with - I've not worked with web workers enough to know quickly if they're doing something wrong, but I can see clearly that code inside the web worker logic affects the original data in IE10.